# Why use “has” for a plural subject here?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

As you can see from the picture, this is a paragraph from Time. I think "memories" is the subject, but "has" is used here. Did I get it wrong?[image]

Comment: Yes, I think it's a slip and it should be _have_ - or 'the memory... has'.

Comment: Thanks. I think they should use grammar checking software xD.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a typo

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Always type out the context.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a typo error.

*Memory* in this sense is countable, and hence a plural verb should be used for present tense constructions.

As the sentence involved is of past tense construction, *had* would be more appropriate.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/memory

> memory noun (EVENT REMEMBERED)
> [ C or U ]
> something that you remember from the past:
> I have vivid memories of that evening.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your quick response.